# razorpages: redirect to page in another folder

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

i am simply trying:

```
   public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("~/Areas/Registration/Index");
    }
```

But this leads to an error, as the page is not in the same folder.

If I tried this with any other page from the same folder, it would work.

I am in Index.cshtml and want to go to Areas/Registration/Index.cshtml

What would I do different?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure that @Steve's said is right, you need to have a Pages folder under the Registration folder.  You can see [Areas with Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#areas-with-razor-pages):

> Areas with Razor Pages require an Areas/`<area name>`/Pages folder in
> the root of the app.

Refer the following folder structure:

[image]

But, you need to use `area` not `areas`.

```
return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "Registration" });
```

Result:

[image]